# Extract misclassified images using CNN keras

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I am having difficulties extracting  misclassified images, I tried to use the following line of code:

```
inc= np.nonzero(model.predict_classes(test_data).reshape(-1,))
print (inc)
```

but this doesn't work, can somebody help me? i would like to use the images in a research paper.

Answer (score 2):

Vaelin,

your code will only give you indices of the misclassified objects. To get the object themselves you should apply the index to the objects array. It will look somewhat like this:

```
misclasssified_objs = test_data[inc]
```